# How can I switch between textmate and terminal quickly?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut-menu

Is it possible to have a short cut so I can jump between Textmate and terminal quickly?

I know I can do it via cmd+tab but I still have to find it from the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways doing this.

The quickest and easiest is to use `Spaces`.

Put `Textmate` on `Desktop 4` and `Terminal` on `Desktop 3`

Then you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd> and either <kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>4</kbd> to switch between the two.

Personally I use `Keyboard Maestro` for this. I used to use a `Service` and a keyboard shortcut but a "feature" of the new security system makes it impossible for a Service to use the System Event library unless you turn on `accessibility` for every app. You need that to select "Bring All to Front".

Answer (score 1):

I currently use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html) to assign shortcuts to applications. For example this [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) would make F7 open iTerm and control-option-command-M open TextMate:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef><name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_ITERM</name><url>file:///Applications/iTerm.app</url></vkopenurldef>
  <vkopenurldef><name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_TEXTMATE</name><url>file:///Applications/TextMate.app</url></vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F7 | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_ITERM</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::M, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_TEXTMATE</autogen>
 </item>
</root>
```

If you have bought the Powerpack for Alfred, you can create a workflow like this:

[image]

Hotkeys have a short delay by default, but you can reduce it by changing the trigger behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OS X Lion or later, you can place the two applications on neighboring spaces. Then use gestures to switch between them. I know terminal supports full screen; not sure about TextMate, though.

Make sure you turn off auto-arrangement in the Mission Control preferences, if you wish. This can effect the order of your apps. I find it annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) and have the powerpack, setting up a workflow to switch to a specific application is easy.

1. Open Alfred's Preferences.
2. Click the Workflows button.
3. Add a new, blank workflow using the '+' button at the bottom of the window.
4. Fill in the Workflow name, for example "Switch to Terminal" and any other info you want and click Save.
5. Using the round '+' button in the top right corner, add a hotkey from the Triggers menu.
6. Set the Hotkey to whichever key combination you want to use. Leave the other defaults.
7. Again using the round '+' button, add an action 'Launch Apps / Files'
8. Find Terminal in the Finder and drag it into the empty list and click Save
9. Connect the Hotkey command to the Launch action by moving the mouse pointer over the side of the hotkey and clicking and dragging the small 'knob' that appears over to the launch action.

Do the same for TextMate and you're done, having two shortcuts to switch to the application you want. (Yes, the action says launch, but if an app is already open Alfred will switch to it instead.)

Answer (score 0):

I use [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com) for this.
It can be configured to open and close a terminal window using a hotkey.

My setup is such that tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice brings up a full-screen terminal window with slightly transparent background, so that I can see what's behind it. Tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> twice again hides the window.